# Send same inputs to different actions with one form

Tags: php, jquery, html, form-submit

I have two input fields and **I want to post the same data to two different php files**, depending on whatever button is clicked.

In my case the data is going into `foo.php` only, but not into `excel.php`.

**I want the data to go to excel.php, if second button is pressed.**

---

**JS**:

```
$(function() {

  $("#from").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
      $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
  });

  $("#to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
      $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
  });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
     <label for="from">From</label>
     <input type="text" id="from" name="from" />

     <label for="to">to</label>
     <input type="text" id="to" name="to" /> <br>

     <input type="submit" value="Viewchart">
</form>

<form action="excel.php" method="post">
     <input type="submit" value="Download Excel file">
</form>
```

Comment: Why would you have two separate forms?

Comment: yes @tomloprod it did not work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change the `action` attribute when the button is clicked as follow:

```
$(function() { 
    $( ".actionable" ).click( function() {
        $('#myForm').attr('action', $(this).data("action"));
        $('#myForm').submit();
    });
});
```

And set the next `data-*` attributes to your buttons:

```
<form name="form" id="myForm" method="post">
    <input type="submit" class="actionable" value="Viewchart" data-action="foo.php"/>
    <input type="submit" class="actionable" value="Excel" data-action="excel.php"/>
</form>
```

You can see how it works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tomloprod/u8vhrxot/).

---

#### Related links:

- You can read more about the `data-*` attributes here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

> **Clarification for OP:**
>
> The `$( function() {} );` block —equivalent to `$(document).ready( function() {} );`—  specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded; you **should** put inside all your code which interact with the elements of the DOM.

Comment: this is a really clean solution it can be used with more than two actions. ty @tomloprod

Comment: @dparoli ;-) The best thing here would be to add a `class` to the buttons to capture the click event. In this way you can use all the buttons (actions) as you need.

Comment: I thought the same thing the first time I saw the solution :-) anyway its even cleaner now. I'll add to my library.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in your way by next script and little change in second form declaration

for second form you should set id:

```
<form id="form2" action="excel.php" method="post">
```

And you should add the next script:

```
$("#form2").submit( function(eventObj){
$(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="from" value="'+$("#from").val()+'" /> ');  
$(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="to" value="'+$("#to").val()+'" /> ');               
return true;
});
```

Comment: I've done it as close as the try of the user asking that question. Any way I think the @tomloprod's way is better or at least much beautiful. At all if we will use script, then no mater to be used 2 forms.

Comment: But have you removed the second form and added the fields #from and #to - You have to get his code, add to his form the fields #from & #to from your sample and the result is whole form code.

Answer (score -2):

That happens because you have one form with action="foo.php". It doesn't matter which button you click it will always send the data to the action of the form in this case "foo.php". 
**Solution:**
Seperate the inputs into two forms and set the action of the second form to "excel.php". Then it should work. Hope it helped you.

Edit: Saw the second form in the last second. In this case you just have to take the input of "to" or "from" down to the second form.

Comment: But I want just one form, I don't need to display two forms